# Beginner Apex Class - For Cases

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I was thrown into the Salesforce position (without training) and I am being asked to create a way for incoming emails to cases to be parsed out into the details section. The incoming emails always come the same way / format and I already have them being forwarded to cases. I am hoping I can create something that will see Quantity: and then pull the numbers to the right of the : and put them into the Quantity details.

First thing I am trying to write a apex class to begin this but I am completely lost. Does anyone have insight on where to begin?

Thank you so much!

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com is the place to get started. Trailhead is a lot more step-by-step, and between the trails (like "Developer Beginner", and "Apex Basics and Database") and the follow-along projects, that should give you a decent foundation. If you're not familiar with Object-Oriented Programming though, you should find some resources on that before trying to dive into Apex.

Comment: Sweet thank you, I am not familiar with any programming, so this will be interesting. I will start with trailhead and see what happens. Is there a basic apex class to just get the email from inside cases and begin breaking out what I need?

Comment: Also check Salesforce and other channels on Youtube, and online learning sites like PluralSight.  Is your company going to pay for your training?

Comment: In addition to the answer from sfdcfox, you may wish to look at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_what_is.htm; which is probably overkill for what you need right now but may be interesting to know about.

Answer (score 2):

There's no One True Way to this, but probably one of the easiest is to use what we call a Regular Expression. Inside your trigger, however that logic looks like, you'd do something like this:

```
Pattern thePattern = Pattern.compile('Quantity:\\s*(\\d+)');
for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
  if(record.Description != null) {
    Matcher theMatcher = thePattern.matcher(record.Description);
    if(theMatcher.find()) {
      record.Quantity__c = Integer.valueOf(theMatcher.group(1));
    }
  }
}
```

For more information, check out the Apex Developer Guide for [Using Patterns and Matchers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm), the Integer class for how `Integer.valueOf` works.

Note that this logic presumes your trigger will be a *before insert* trigger, since we want to modify the record before it is saved to the database.

You'll also want to go through the Apex Triggers [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers) and probably the entire Developer Beginner [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/force_com_dev_beginner).